# How to use SQL result in OCI_BIND_BY_NAME

Tags: php, html, oracle-call-interface

I'm new in oci connection. I want to use the result from SQL as a data to be inserted into the other table in db. Here my code

```
      $search = "SELECT STAFF_ID FROM LIBRARIAN WHERE LIB_ID = $_id";
      $querysearch = oci_parse($link, $search) or die ("Query failed");
      oci_execute($querysearch);

       oci_result($querysearch, 'STAFF_ID');

      $sqllib="INSERT INTO LIBRARIAN(LIB_ID, LIB_NAME, LIB_CONTACT, STAFF_ID) VALUES (:id, :name, :contact, :staff)";
      $querylib=oci_parse($link, $sqllib) or die ("error insert Librarian");

      oci_bind_by_name($querylib, ':staff', $querysearch);
      oci_bind_by_name($querylib, ':id', $lib_id);
      oci_bind_by_name($querylib, ':name', $lib_name);
      oci_bind_by_name($querylib, ':contact', $lib_contact);
```

But do you know how can I use staff id that i get from select statement and insert it into another table and how i should bind?

From this code, i get error

> Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): Invalid variable used for bind in C:\xampp\htdocs\SYSTEM\admin-insert-lib.php on line 216

With your help really it would help me a lot. And i appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues that are likely causing this problem:

1. An [`oci_fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch.php) call is required to read the query result row so that it's accessible to `oci_result`
2. `$querysearch` is not being set to the STAFF_ID returned by your `$search` SELECT query

To fix these problems, try this:

```
oci_execute($querysearch);
oci_fetch($querysearch);
$staff_id = oci_result($querysearch, 'STAFF_ID');
```

Then, pass this `$staff_id` in the `oci_bind_by_name` line in your INSERT query like this:

`oci_bind_by_name($querylib, ':staff', $staff_id);`

Edit: I'm assuming your $lib_id, $lib_name, and $lib_contact variables are defined outside of this snippet and also that they have valid values for :id, :name, and :contact.

Comment: Can i know what if  i want to oci_result ($query, count('book')) ? like this:- $sql = "SELECT COUNT(BOOK_ID) FROM BORROW WHERE BOOK_ID = '$book_id'";
      $query = oci_parse($link, $sql);
      oci_execute($query);
      oci_fetch($query);
      $res = oci_result($query, 'BOOK_ID');

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using insert staffid, i used to update the col only by using where condition

```
 $sqllib="INSERT INTO LIBRARIAN(LIB_ID, LIB_NAME, LIB_CONTACT) VALUES (:id, :name, :contact)";
          $querylib=oci_parse($link, $sqllib) or die ("error insert Librarian");

          //oci_bind_by_name($querylib, ':staff', $try);
          oci_bind_by_name($querylib, ':id', $lib_id);
          oci_bind_by_name($querylib, ':name', $lib_name);
          oci_bind_by_name($querylib, ':contact', $lib_contact);

          oci_execute($querylib);

          $query = "UPDATE LIBRARIAN SET STAFF_ID = (SELECT STAFF_ID FROM LIBRARIAN WHERE LIB_ID = '$_id') WHERE LIB_ID = '$lib_id'";
          $Query1 = oci_parse($link, $query);
          oci_execute($Query1);
```